# If we know the probability of an event $H$ is zero, why do we say that $E[|X|\chi_H]=0 \, a.s.?$

Tags: probability

Given a random variable $X\in L^1$. If we know the probability of an event $H$ is zero, why do we say that
$$E[|X|\chi_H]=0 \, a.s.?$$

I can understand it because $P(H)=0$, then $\chi_H=0$ a.s. So the expectation is zeor. But how to prove it formally?

Comment: What is $\chi_H$?

Comment: $\chi_H$ is the indicator function of $H$.

Comment: Hint: consider the sequence $\min(|X|,n)\uparrow |X|$ and monotone convergence.

Comment: @Snoop Where is your $n$ from?

Comment: @quasAliki the sequence is $Y_n=\min(|X|,n)$. Also be careful about how you use 'a.s.' in the OP

Comment: @Snoop I am confused about the motivation of taking $Y_n$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By law of iterated expectation, first conditional on $1_{H}$
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[|X|1_{H}]&=\mathbb{E}\bigl[\mathbb{E}[|X|1_{H}|1_{H}]\bigr]\\&=\mathbb{P}(H)\cdot\mathbb{E}[|X|]+\mathbb{P}(H^{c})\cdot0\\&=0.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I am not sure if I am right in your second equality. I get $E[E[|X|1_H|1_H]]=E[1_HE[|X||1_H]]=E[|X|] E[1_H]=E|X| P(H)?$ Can you explain more about it? Thanks!

Comment: The conditional expectation is a (discrete value) random variable, takes value $\mathbb{E}[|X|]$ if $1_{H}=1$, takes value $0$ otherwise. So its expectation is just $\mathbb{P}(H)\mathbb{E}[|X|]+\mathbb{P}(H^{c})\cdot0$.

Comment: Any reason for downvoting this answer?